# LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY brings to double rows

Tags: sql

I am getting doublicated data when running this code the code below. Anyone to help me out?

The target is to have a list of products and respective order in the first two columns over certain time period. Items may be repeated since there mught be several orderal orders for the same product. Finally, in the third column I want to see a sum of overall sales of this product regardless the order number. All in all, it should be something like this:

product - order - overall sales of product (sales per order, overall sales)

```
SELECT
    OBITNO as "product", 
    OBORNO as "Order #",
    summary
FROM MVXJDTA.OOLINE 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    OBITNO as "product", 
    sum(OBORQA) as "summary" 
    FROM MVXJDTA.OOLINE 
    WHERE OBCONO=2 and OBWHLO=091 and OBCODT>20190701 group by OBITNO) md2
    on OBITNO=OBITNO
WHERE OBCONO=2 and OBWHLO=091 and OBCODT>20190701
```

Answer (score 1):

Your join is not correct:

```
`on OBITNO=OBITNO`
```

In your subquery you have given the column `OBITNO` an alias of `product`, so both sides of the equality operator are the same column, since this is always going to be true, you are getting a cross join. Instead you should use `ON md2.Product = OOLINE.OBITNO`:

```
SELECT
        o.OBITNO as "product", 
        o.OBORNO as "Order #",
        md2.summery
FROM    MVXJDTA.OOLINE AS o
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  o.OBITNO as "product", 
                    SUM(o.OBORQA) as "summery" 
            FROM    MVXJDTA.OOLINE  AS o
            WHERE   o.OBCONO=2 
            AND     o.OBWHLO=091 
            AND     o.OBCODT>20190701 
            GROUP BY o.OBITNO
        ) AS md2
            ON md2.product = o.OBITNO
WHERE   o.OBCONO=2 
AND     o.OBWHLO=091 
AND     o.OBCODT>20190701
```

I tend to make sure that I prefix every column name with the table alias (often even when there is only one table), this makes it much easier for people to work out where data is coming from when reading my queries, it also means that things like this happen much less, as it results in errors (i.e.`md2.OBITNO` is not a valid column reference)

Comment: oh wow! that looks much better now! I indeed thought of wrong equation `on OBITNO=OBITNO` but you solved it. Thank you for you help and the hint with regards to "As o". Cheers, Artemiy

Comment: Me again! I was thankful to find you help here the last time and I am curious if you'll be able to share your expertise again. The is is the same code that we discussed before already. It is stopped working all of a sudden a few weeks ago. SQL runs it for the maximum aallowed time and give a zero result finally. I have tried to split the code into 2, main part and virtual table, and run them seperate to see if there were any mistakes but both worked fine. Do you possiby know what may have happened?

Comment: If nothing at all has changed, then the most likely reason is that the accumulation of data means that your query is now much slower than it was, and is timing out. Your best bet is to ask a new question that includes (1) the SQL you are executing (2) Your DMBS (mysql, SQL Server, Oracle etc) (3) The details of the tables you are querying (data types of columns, primary keys, any indexes, and approximate number of records) and (4) The execution plan for the query (if possible). All this should be enough for someone to suggest a solution

Comment: Thank you for the quick responce! I have finally decided to re-write the code step by step myslef and it worked. Unfortunately, I did not find the mistake but at least I got a working code.

Answer (score 0):

The duplication will be coming from something in your join - but I don't think the join is really necessary. Unless I'm misunderstanding, you seem to be doing a join to the same table in order to get the sum. But you can just get the sum inline using a windowing function.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    OBITNO as "product", 
    OBORNO as "Order #",
    sum(OBORQA) over(partition by OBITNO) as "summery" 
FROM MVXJDTA.OOLINE 
WHERE OBCONO=2 and OBWHLO=091 and OBCODT>20190701
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to aliases

```
SELECT OBITNO as "product"
    , OBORNO as "Order #"
    , summery FROM MVXJDTA.OOLINE md1 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT OBITNO as "product"
            , sum(OBORQA) as "summery" 
              FROM MVXJDTA.OOLINE WHERE OBCONO=2 and OBWHLO=091 and 
              OBCODT>20190701 group by OBITNO) md2 
    on md2.OBITNO=md1.OBITNO
WHERE md2.OBCONO=2 and md2.OBWHLO=091 and md2.OBCODT>20190701
```